# How can I force folders created in a subdirectory to be owned by a user's secondary group?

Tags: permissions, ldap, samba

I have setup a Samba share on Ubuntu 12.04 for our finance team, and they access it via Windows 7 and Mac OS X. They mount the share using their LDAP credentials. All of our LDAP users have "employees" as their primary group, and the finance team belongs to a secondary group named "finance".

When any of the finance team members create a folder within the Samba share, the folder's group defaults to "employees". How can I force all files and folders created on the share to have the group set to "finance"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For share foo, with path /bar/foo, the following in your `smb.conf` file should do it:

```
[foo]
        path = /bar/foo
        force create mode = 0020
        force directory mode = 0030
        force group = +finance
```

The mode statements are to ensure that all directories and files created via samba are group-writeable: it's no good just being group-owned by the right group if that group has no privileges to do anything.

Comment: Can you explain how "force create mode" and "force directory mode" work? I can't really figure out what this is telling me: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#FORCECREATEMODE

Comment: As used above, the first says that regular files must have the group-write bit on, whatever else they may or may not have; the second that all directories must have the group write and execute bits on, whatever else they may or may not have.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I like this solution the best, as I can use it within my samba configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setfacl for this purpose. [Man setfacl here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl). Setfacl allows you to set ownerships and rights different than default ones. [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/444867/linux-setfacl-set-all-current-future-files-directories-in-parent-directory-to) is a similar question which can also helps you: