# How to set ACL recursively using setfacl for files/dir added after executing setfacl

Tags: linux, permissions, access-control-list

my directory hierarchy looks like this

```
/tmp/
    dir/
       subdir/
       file
```

so i try command (found on a similar issue [linux/setfacl - Set all current/future files/directories in parent directory to 775 with specified owner/group](https://serverfault.com/questions/444867/linux-setfacl-set-all-current-future-files-directories-in-parent-directory-to?rq=1))

```
setfacl -Rm u::rwX,d:u::rwX tmp/
setfacl -Rdm u::rwX,d:u::rwX tmp/
```

it works fine, all file and directories are affected, but when i add a new file

```
/tmp/
    dir/
       subdir/
       file 
       file2
```

it doesnt affect file2, i also tried with small x

```
setfacl -Rm u::rwx,d:u::rwx tmp/
setfacl -Rdm u::rwx,d:u::rwx tmp/
```

but it doesn't work, can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: We need to see the desired vs. actual ACLs on `file2`.  Can we see contrasting `getfacl` on `file` and `file2`?

Comment: file1 goes as planned but file2 gets default permissions

Comment: I believe the `umask` figures in to new files even when ACLs are used. Check in with https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I don't see the point of using ACLs if there aren't at least two users or groups involved. I can't see any specific user or group mentioned in the question.

Comment: the user is not the issue i can  add a user if it's necessary, i want to give the premissions to files added automatically

Answer (score 0):

As you are telling us, when you apply an [ACL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-control-listsacl-linux/#:%7E:text=ACL%20allows%20you%20to%20give,Use%20of%20ACL%20%3A&text=Basically%2C%20ACLs%20are%20used%20to,rights%20for%20files%20and%20directories.) permissions, you only apply to this changes to the existing path and files, but if you create a new file, the user isn’t allowed to read, write or execute it.

You have two options, change all the permissions for the path recursively, or add as a default user with ACLs, this change will add the user to the list and all the files created will have the permissions executed on the command.

> setfacl -d -m u::rwx tmp/

Please consider if you want all the users to have these permissions, I think the best option would be to change it with the command [chmod](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions)