# How to change the owner of a file to that user when a user modifies a file

Tags: ftp, user-management, owner

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 version.
I want to satisfy two conditions in an environment with multiple users.
Users will all upload files via ftp.

Multiple users should be active in one home directory.
And in order to know who the last person was, when a user modifies a file, the owner of that file should be changed to the user who modified the file.

The first condition seems to be possible, but I have no idea what to do with the second condition.
Can vsftp satisfy both of the above conditions?
How should I configure it?

Comment: You can do what you want using ACLs. Check out [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/444867/linux-setfacl-set-all-current-future-files-directories-in-parent-directory-to).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [linux/setfacl - Set all current/future files/directories in parent directory to 775 with specified owner/group](https://serverfault.com/questions/444867/linux-setfacl-set-all-current-future-files-directories-in-parent-directory-to)

Comment: The post above seems a bit different from what I was looking for.. Thanks for your help.